# GUI for Postgres upgrade

Tags: postgresql

I am interested in upgrading Postgresql database from  version 14 to version 15.
Is there a GUI to do so, since I am not experienced in Postgres?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @dwhitemv Linux

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, there are no GUI-based tools for performing major PostgreSQL upgrades on Linux/UNIX/BSD. The exact upgrade procedure depends on how PostgreSQL was installed (and thus, likely, the Linux distribution you are using) and major upgrades happen so infrequently that a GUI would not provide much value.

Marking this answer as wiki so it can be updated in the future.